# What are some examples of "lesser manifestations" of a ghost?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead

One of the main villains I've been creating for my campaign is a ghost. The *Bestiary* says that before the party encounters a ghost, the part should encounter lesser manifestations of that ghost.

But I'm having trouble finding examples of lesser manifestations. I assume lesser manifestations are other undead creatures, but does the ghost control these creatures? And where does the ghost get them? Are they somehow the summoned or did they just kind of migrate to the ghost's presence by virtue of the ghost being a more powerful undead creature than they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This isn't a rule but a scenario building advice.

[Here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/ghost) is the quote of the relevant part:

> More than most of the monsters in this book, a ghost benefits from a strong and detailed backstory. Why did this character become a ghost? What are the legends surrounding the ghost? An encounter with a ghost should never happen completely out of the blue—there are plenty of other incorporeal undead like wraiths and spectres to fill that role. A proper encounter with a ghost should be a climactic scene after a lengthy period of tension building with lesser minions or manifestations of the undead spirit. The sample ghost above is that of a human princess who was murdered by an unfaithful lover—after she confronted him, he murdered her by wrapping her in chains and throwing her into the castle well, where she drowned. The ghost’s abilities were selected to fit this backstory, and it shows how potent a villain you can create with a simple NPC class.

To sum up: ghosts are too cool for being simple minions. For the best effect the DM has to prepare the ghost's entrance.

Examples of ways to build up the necessary tension are encounters with minions (like lesser tormented spirits: shadows, allip... or even mad cultist that venerate the ghost, nothing is impossible) or "manifestations".

These manifestations can be [haunts](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/haunts/) or even not formally ruled events: a pale silhouette at the window that suddenly disappear, a stain of blood that moves when you don't looks at it... with no mechanical effects, just to scare the PCs (and the players!)

Compare the following two scenarios:

> The PCs are traveling and suddenly in the middle of the road an horrible ghost appears an attacks! It has tentacles coming out of his eyes and a dark shroud of evilness around him. Roll for initiative.
>
> The PCs are traveling and for a mysterious reason their compass seems to always bring them in from of the same shady abandoned mansion. As they decide to camp outside of it they hear during the night help screams coming from inside: "But I can't let them like that! Dad told me to bring them food.". It's the voice of a young human girl, screaming like she was suffering intensely. The PCs decide to enter to save her and as they open the door they notice a long corridor ornamented with hunt trophies. The interior is dark and as they are inside all their lights turn off. Just to reappear a few second later except that the door disappeared: now they are in a long seemingly infinite corridor. As they try a transversal door they discover what used to be a kennel, except the skeletons of the dogs suddenly attack them. After defeating them they hear the door behind them closing by itself. They manage to re-open it and are back in the corridor. Listening to the screams of the girl they finally enter a child's bedroom where a little girl is crying, cowering in a corner of the room. As they go prudently forward she turns into a giant half-dog ghost and attacks. After the fight the PCs can find her journal where she explains her tragic backstory: she was the daughter of some noble passionated by hunting, her mother was dead, and at some point her father went to war. She was left alone in the house but she forgot to feed the dogs. After a few weeks she finally found the courage to do so but the dogs were so hungry that they eat her alive. This known the PCs only have to fetch her remains that lie among the dog skeletons and offer them decent funerals to appease the ghost.

Which one is the scariest?

Answer (score 4):

It may well mean "general spooky things." Those would include unexplained noises, mysterious cold drafts, objects moving, poltergeists, hallucinations, and any other horror phenomena you feel like ladling into the adventure. Ghosts should be at least a bit special and atmospheric, not just something more to kill.

Comment: I want to up vote this, because it "feels" right... Can you provide some argument or evidence supporting this supposition?

Comment: Not really. It's a plausible interpretation of a quote from a book I don't have.